# How to call servlet when jsp is load

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to get latest data to my home page by calling servlet, means when user click on refresh button home page should fill with most recent data. For that i used

jsp:forward page="tests"/>.

But finally I end up with redirect loop. Soo how can I achieve this? 
myservlet is this :

```
 RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("tt.jsp");
 view.forward(request, response);
```

How I am going to do this with out getting into never ending loop?

Comment: NOT enough info, please share both JSP(src) and Sevlet(target) codez.

Comment: You probably just need to set no-cache headers on your servlet and JSP rather than making the JSP forward to the servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem successfully by checking attribute is null.
code:
    <%
        if((request.getAttribute("vdata") == null) || request.getAttribute("ldata") == null ||
                 request.getAttribute("mdata") == null){

%>

jsp:forward page="intial_getdata"/>